# Centerize canvas text at all time, even if resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am currently trying to work on this script, which was created by someone else. Yes, I grabbed it, yes I will give credits.

The problem I am having, is trying to center the text even if the window has been resized. When you move the cursor on the text, it explodes randomly. When I resize the window, I need that same text (and those exploded characters) to move. I can easily just put new text in using `fillText()`, but then I replace the exploded characters.

Obviously I have tried this in my example:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    reload(canvas_id);
}

var reload = function(canvas_id) {
    canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
}
```

This resizes the canvas perfectly, but the text won't be centered anymore. To center the text when I place it, I do this:

```
(window.innerWidth / 2) - (Math.round(bgContext.measureText(keyword).width/2))
```

`bgContext` being the `canvas.getContext("2d");` obviously.

Here's a JSFiddle showing this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/2e8o5db8/1/

Answer (score 3):

First, tell canvas to draw text aligned from a center X rather than the default left-aligned

```
context.textAlign = 'center';
```

And then set the x,y in `fillText` to the center of the canvas.

```
fillText('Hello', canvas.width/2, 50);
```

By using `canvas.width/2` you will redraw the text at center-canvas even if the canvas is resized.

You will have to redraw the text after using canvas.width=... because the canvas contents will automatically be cleared.

Comment: So you want me to use fillText(); in the reload? Because that won't work.

Comment: Your example resizes the canvas with `canvas.width=...`. That will cause the canvas contents to automatically be cleared. So...yes...if you want the text again displayed after the canvas is erased you will have to do another `fillText`. ;-)

Comment: Let's assume I destroy some of the text (move the cursor around the text), then I resize the image... By using your way, I will be replacing the text and not moving it. I need to MOVE the text. Let's assume this is a game. You play Tic-tac-toe or something like that. If you resize the window, do you want to replace your current score with 0? No. You want to MOVE the game and not replace it.

Comment: Canvas will automatically erase itself when it is resized (eg canvas.width=...) -- It's just the way canvas is designed. So you will indeed have to redraw your entire tic-tac-toe display. You can use CSS to resize the canvas, but be sure to resize it proportionally or your game will appear stretched or squished.

Comment: Yep so the canvas will get resized but the text/game/whatever inside won't get moved with it. That's the issue I have and I know it's possible.

Comment: @Snorlax Ouch! Please don't downvote me...I'm just telling you the realities of the html5 canvas.

Comment: I downvoted you because your "answer" wasn't an answer that fixed or helped my issue. Obviously your answer won't help me in any way, so why post it? Let's not keep discussing. If you have an answer, let me know and I will upvote and mark yours as the correct answer, but let's not discuss this here.

Comment: markE is correct. When you play Halo, and Master Chief strafes right three feet, the Xbox is not "moving" the game world left three feet. It maintains all the logic it needs to completely redraw the world, relative to changes in state and does so every frame. It can even do this instantaneously after the user changes the game's resolution; it's not resizing the rasterized game frame. You need to do a complete redraw, because unlike standard HTML elements, canvases work more like Halo (or any game); end of story.

Comment: @Katana314 Sure thing. So you're saying it's absolutely impossible to move an object/text once it has been placed on a canvas?

Comment: @Snorlax. Correct, it's absolutely impossible to move an individual text once it has been placed on a canvas. You can redraw it and even move the canvas element itself so the text moves relative to the window but canvas text is like dried paint...immovable.

Comment: Hmm. Moving the canvas might be the best idea then. I see no harm in that to be honest. So let's say it's a game of Tetris. If you resize the browser while playing, the game has to remember where every brick is, then redraw the whole canvas and put the bricks back in again?

Comment: @Snorlax Most tetris games are remembering where every brick is, and redrawing the whole canvas, *every time a block moves at all*. There are occasions you can avoid that draw (only for computational savings, not programming effort savings) but it will either be extremely difficult, or severely limit what you can actually change each frame. Basically, shitfting the frame is outside the scope of this discussion.

Comment: @Katana314 I see. Thanks for that explanation. I'll proceed with the moving, as that will work ;)

Comment: @Katana314 Hah, now after moving it using margin, it won't detect my mouse movement correctly. It's way off. Guess I'll have to look at this in another way :p